# Graphing an Integral on Mathematica - has something to do with the erfc function

Tags: plotting

I was scrolling through a research article and this was a curve that modeled the theoretical bit-error-rate from BPSK modulation.

[image]

I was wondering what it would look like on a graph. I had just recently gotten Mathematica and I was wondering how I could make the graph. I tried for 30 minutes or so but I could not get it. Could anyone help out?

Comment: Please share what you tried.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Mma.SE. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, **show due diligence**, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. The site depends on participation, as you receive **give back:** vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Minimum *due diligence* includes searching the documentation for the keyworks of your question, and share what is that you found and why that wasn't enough to solve your problem. Now your question may be put [on-hold](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD) as [off-topic](https://goo.gl/bnZVrD), because it's easily found in the documentation and unlikely to help any future visitors. Don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your future [good questions](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) are welcome. Learn about [common pitfalls here](https://goo.gl/XAcNDp).

Answer (score 2):

First, you have $x$ appearing as both the variable of integration and the lower limit on the integral.  What you want is the definition $$Q(x)={1\over\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_x^\infty e^{-{u^2/2}}\,du\,.$$  Now use the Mathematica command

```
  Q[x_]=1/Sqrt[2 Pi] Integrate[Exp[-u^2/2],{u,x,Infinity}]
```

It returns the expression ${1\over2} \operatorname{erfc} {x\over \sqrt{2}}$ for $Q(x)$.  (Note , $\operatorname{erfc}(x)\equiv 1-\operatorname{erf}(x))$. Now, to get a plot, use the command

```
  Plot[Q[x],{x,-5,5}]
```

Answer (score 0):

First; evaluate:

```
 PDF[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]]][x]
```

and view the result.

Second; letting Mu=0 and Sigma=1 above, evaluate:

```
  PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1]][x]
```

Third; evaluate:

```
Integrate[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1]][x], x]
```

Finally; to visualize the area evaluate:

```
Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1]][x], {x, -6, 6}, Filling -> Axis]
```